cpuset is turned on, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuset.cpus is not found
My cpuset controller is enabled, but I don't find the corresponding file, I want to know why, any help is greatly appreciated ^_^
OS
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$hostnamectl
 Static hostname: liruilongs.github.io
       Icon name: computer-vm
         Chassis: vm 
      Machine ID: 7deac2815b304f9795f9e0a8b0ae7765
         Boot ID: 4789d089b50042d88e660a1c511c92ab
  Virtualization: vmware
Operating System: Rocky Linux 9.3 (Blue Onyx)
     CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:rocky:rocky:9::baseos
          Kernel: Linux 5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.0.1.x86_64
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: VMware, Inc.
  Hardware Model: VMware Virtual Platform
Firmware Version: 6.00
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$

cpuset enable
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$ls /sys/fs/cgroup/
cgroup.controllers      cgroup.threads         init.scope        sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
cgroup.max.depth        cpu.stat               io.stat           sys-kernel-config.mount
cgroup.max.descendants  cpuset.cpus.effective  memory.numa_stat  sys-kernel-debug.mount
cgroup.procs            cpuset.mems.effective  memory.reclaim    sys-kernel-tracing.mount
cgroup.stat             dev-hugepages.mount    memory.stat       system.slice
cgroup.subtree_control  dev-mqueue.mount       misc.capacity     user.slice
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$cat /proc/filesystems  | grep cpuset
nodev   cpuset
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuset.cpus
cat: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuset.cpus: No such file or directory


This is because different versions of cgroup have different corresponding restrictions. The cpuset controller is not directly supported in the v2 version. The cpuset controller is a feature in cgroup v1, which allows administrators to assign specific CPU cores and memory nodes to processes in a cgroup. In cgroup v2, the cpuset feature is integrated into the unified resource management, and a separate cpuset controller is no longer provided.
Configure as Demo with CPU affinity
Cgroup V1
Starting from Linux 4.6, the cpuset API has been marked as obsolete, and it is recommended to use the unified cgroup v2 API based on the file system. In the cgroup v1 version. Multiple CPUs can be assigned to process tasks in the following way
Currently used experimental environment
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset]
└─$hostnamectl
   Static hostname: vms99.liruilongs.github.io
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: ea70bf6266cb413c84266d4153276342
           Boot ID: 28c693c2b1fc4d45935d6daf6296cece
    Virtualization: vmware
  Operating System: Rocky Linux 8.9 (Green Obsidian)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:rocky:rocky:8:GA
            Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-513.9.1.el8_9.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset]
└─$

Determine the Cgroup version
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$mount -l | grep cgroup
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,rdma)

Cgroup v1 version allocates each CPU core of a multi-core system to a process task through the cpuset controller. cpuset is in the /sys/fs/cgroup directory.
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset]
└─$ls /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
cgroup.clone_children  cpuset.mem_exclusive            cpuset.mems
cgroup.procs           cpuset.mem_hardwall             cpuset.sched_load_balance
cgroup.sane_behavior   cpuset.memory_migrate           cpuset.sched_relax_domain_level
cpuset.cpu_exclusive   cpuset.memory_pressure          notify_on_release
cpuset.cpus            cpuset.memory_pressure_enabled  release_agent
cpuset.effective_cpus  cpuset.memory_spread_page       tasks
cpuset.effective_mems  cpuset.memory_spread_slab
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset]
└─$

The control files under /sys/fs/cgroup can be read and modified manually

The cpuset.cpus file lists the CPU cores that can be used by processes in the cgroup. 0-5 means that CPU cores 0 to 5 are available.
The cpuset.mems file lists the memory nodes that can be used by processes in the cgroup. On systems without NUMA enabled, there is actually only one memory area, so you will usually only see 0 in the cpuset.mems file.

┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset]
└─$cat cpuset.cpus
0-5
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset]
└─$cat cpuset.mems
0

Each running process will have a cpuset file in the /proc directory, which lists the cgroup directory to which the process is bound. The default value is /(cgroup's root directory)
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset]
└─$cat /proc/1/cpuset
/

Configure the service CPU affinity through the cpuset controller. Here we use httpd as a demo.
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset]
└─$systemctl enable --now httpd
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/httpd.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.

View current affinity
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset]
└─$pgrep httpd
37923
37924
37925
37926
37927
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset]
└─$egrep Cpu /proc/3792?/status
/proc/37923/status:Cpus_allowed:        ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff
/proc/37923/status:Cpus_allowed_list:   0-127
/proc/37924/status:Cpus_allowed:        ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff
/proc/37924/status:Cpus_allowed_list:   0-127
/proc/37925/status:Cpus_allowed:        ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff
/proc/37925/status:Cpus_allowed_list:   0-127
/proc/37926/status:Cpus_allowed:        ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff
/proc/37926/status:Cpus_allowed_list:   0-127
/proc/37927/status:Cpus_allowed:        ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff
/proc/37927/status:Cpus_allowed_list:   0-127
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset]
└─$

The Cpus_allowed field shows which CPU cores the process is allowed to use, and it is usually displayed as a series of ffffffff (in this case, each ffffffff represents a mask of 32 CPU cores, because ffffffff is 32 1s in binary). Since you have four ffffffff, this usually means that your system supports up to 128 CPU cores (32 * 4 = 128), and all of them are allowed to the process.
The Cpus_allowed_list field provides a more human-readable list showing the range of CPU cores that the process is allowed to access. In this case, 0-127 means that the process can run on any CPU core from 0 to 127.
The following changes the affinity of process 40604
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$systemctl restart httpd
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$pgrep httpd
40604
40607
40608
40609
40610

Confirm the current affinity
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$egrep Cpu /proc/40604/status
Cpus_allowed: ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff
Cpus_allowed_list: 0-127

Create a cgroup
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$mkdir -p /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuset0

Configure cpuset, here configure the CPU to allow it to run on the CPU corresponding to 0,1
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$echo 0-1 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuset0/cpuset.cpus
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuset0/cpuset.cpus
0-1

Add the process to cgroup, here is the tasks file, and Cgroup v2 version is different
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$echo 40604 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuset0/tasks
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuset0/tasks
40604

Verify configuration
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$cat /proc/40604/status | grep Cpu
Cpus_allowed:   00000000,00000000,00000000,00000003
Cpus_allowed_list:      0-1

┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$printf "%032x\n" $((2**0+2**1))
00000000000000000000000000000003

Cgroup V2
实验环境
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$hostnamectl
 Static hostname: liruilongs.github.io
 Pretty hostname: VM-16-15-centos
       Icon name: computer-vm
         Chassis: vm 
      Machine ID: 613a0293049a4b07973b2510b3318f11
         Boot ID: e548e77ef4f04d5f80c87ef18f6000c0
  Virtualization: kvm
Operating System: CentOS Stream 9
     CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:9
          Kernel: Linux 5.14.0-437.el9.x86_64
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: Tencent Cloud
  Hardware Model: CVM
Firmware Version: seabios-1.9.1-qemu-project.org
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$

Confirm the Cgroup version used by the current system. The current version is cgroup v2.
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[/sys/fs/cgroup] 
└─$mount | grep cgroup
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[/sys/fs/cgroup] 
└─$which systemd-cgtop
/usr/bin/systemd-cgtop

In cgroup v2, you can view the CPU and memory resources currently accessible to the cgroup through read-only files such as cpuset.cpus.effective and cpuset.mems.effective, but these files are read-only and cannot be modified directly to set the allocation of CPU cores or memory nodes.
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$ls  /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu*
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset.cpus.effective  /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset.mems.effective
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset.cpus.isolated   /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu.stat
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[/sys/fs/cgroup/demogroup] 
└─$ll /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset.cpus.effective 
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  4 16:48 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset.cpus.effective
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset.cpus.effective
0-1
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset.mems.effective
0

To control the CPU affinity of applications in cgroup v2, you need to enable a specific CPU controller and create a dedicated control group. It is recommended to create at least two levels of sub-control groups in the root control group of /sys/fs/cgroup/
Verify that the cpu and cpuset controllers are provided in the /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.controllers file:
.
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.controllers
cpuset cpu io memory hugetlb pids rdma misc

The cpu and cpuset controllers are enabled for direct children of the /sys/fs/cgroup/ root control group. A subgroup is where you can specify the Cgroup hierarchy for processes and apply control checks to each process based on the criteria. Users can read the contents of the cgroup.subtree_control file at any level to know which controllers in a subgroup are available for enabling. By default, the /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control file in the root control group contains the memory and pids controllers.
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control
memory pids
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$echo "+cpu" >> /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$echo "+cpuset" >> /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control
cpuset cpu memory pids
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$

Create the /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/ directory, which defines a subgroup. In addition, the previous step enables the cpu and cpuset controllers for this subgroup.
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$cat /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/cgroup.controllers
cpuset cpu memory pids

When you create the /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/ directory, some cgroups-v2 interface files and cpu and cpuset controller-specific files are also automatically created in the directory. The /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/ directory also contains controller-specific files for the memory and pids controllers.
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$ls /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/
cgroup.controllers      cpuset.cpus.exclusive            memory.oom.group
cgroup.events           cpuset.cpus.exclusive.effective  memory.peak
cgroup.freeze           cpuset.cpus.partition            memory.reclaim
cgroup.kill             cpuset.mems                      memory.stat
cgroup.max.depth        cpuset.mems.effective            memory.swap.current
cgroup.max.descendants  cpu.stat                         memory.swap.events
cgroup.procs            cpu.weight                       memory.swap.high
cgroup.stat             cpu.weight.nice                  memory.swap.max
cgroup.subtree_control  memory.current                   memory.swap.peak
cgroup.threads          memory.events                    memory.zswap.current
cgroup.type             memory.events.local              memory.zswap.max
cpu.idle                memory.high                      pids.current
cpu.max                 memory.low                       pids.events
cpu.max.burst           memory.max                       pids.max
cpuset.cpus             memory.min                       pids.peak
cpuset.cpus.effective   memory.numa_stat
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$

Enable CPU-related controllers in /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/ to get only CPU-related controllers:
──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$echo "+cpu" >> /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/cgroup.subtree_control
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$echo "+cpuset" >> /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/cgroup.subtree_control

Create the /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/tasks/ directory. The /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/tasks/ directory defines a subgroup and files related only to the cpu and cpuset controllers.
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/tasks/
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$cat /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/tasks/cgroup.controllers
cpuset cpu
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$

Configure CPU affinity
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$echo "1" > /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/tasks/cpuset.cpus
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$

Pass httpd service test
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$systemctl enable --now httpd
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$pgrep httpd
879
1096
1098
1105
1106
11313
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$cat /proc/1105/status | grep Cpu
Cpus_allowed: 3
Cpus_allowed_list: 0-1

Add the service's PID to the Example/tasks subgroup:
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$echo "1105" > /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/tasks/cgroup.procs

Verify the configuration
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$cat /proc/1105/status | grep Cpu
Cpus_allowed:   2
Cpus_allowed_list:      1
┌──[root@liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$
┌──[root@vms99.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$printf "%032x\n" $((2**1))
00000000000000000000000000000002

